# Why can't I PATCH Django REST Framework PrimaryKeyRelatedField to empty list?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm running into a weird issue in Django REST Framework. I'm attempting to add & remove groups to/from users using PATCH requests.

I am able to PATCH to `/api/users/:id/` to update the `groups` list, which is initially empty. For example, the following actions yield these results:

1. `PATCH /api/users/:id/ {"groups": [1]}` -> Results in user with `groups: [1]`
2. `PATCH /api/users/:id/ {"groups": [1, 2]}` -> Results in user with `groups: [1,2]`
3. `PATCH /api/users/:id/ {"groups": [1]}` -> Results in user back to `groups: [1]`

So I am successfully updating the state with PATCH requests. However the following fails to update accordingly:

`PATCH /api/users/:id/ {"groups": []}`  -> Results in user still at `groups: [1]`

Here is my UserSerializer class:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,
                                                queryset=Group.objects.all(),
                                                allow_empty=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_authenticated', 'is_superuser', 'email',
            'groups'
        )
```

My suspicion is that it has something to do with `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` - I have tried many combinations of arguments to the constructor to no avail.

Comment: I tried with your serializer configuration, Unfortunately I couldn't able reproduce the issue, means, whatever array I put corresponding to `groups` fields, it just overwriting.

Comment: This is from @[Martini991](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12973643/martini991) but he doesn't have the required reputation to comment:`I've the same issue: the problem is that when you pass an empty list, the PATCH method recognise it like there is "no field" provided. Being so, the strategy for no field is to leave it untouched. You can change the HTTP method to UPDATE and give the whole object to the server again to work-around the problem, but of course is not a solution.`

Comment: as @JPG mentioned, I have tried this same snippet serializer and I have got the result as expected.

Comment: What are the versions of Python, Django and DRF? @c_sagan

Comment: Python 3.8, Django 3.0.6, DRF 3.11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually due to a bug in the `partial_update` override in the `UserViewSet`

PATCH works as expected after fixing this issue, and users using the default `partial_update` Django REST Framework provides shouldn't experience this issue.